# Null for turtle variables

Tags: netlogo

So I'm aware of the lack of `Null` values in Netlogo. I'm not sure how to handle that in my code.

I'm building a search model where turtles go from one patch to another according to different criteria. The way I want to do that is by having a turtle variable `target` that is the next patch they'll go to , which is taken from a turtle variable `itinerary` that is an order list of patches returned by the reporter below.

```
turtles-own
[
target
itinerary
]


to-report most

  ; sets turtle target toward patch with max space
  ; let place-list list patches with [space > 0]

  let list-a sort-on [space] (patches with [space > 0] )

  report list-a

end
```

Coming from R and python my psuedocode simply checks if target is `Null`, and if it is, checks if itinerary is `Null` and if it is calls the reporter procedure to build the ordered list.

Should I just use:

```
ifelse empty? target 
[  
    ;go to target
] 
[
    ifelse empty? itinerary 
    [
        set itinerary most
    [
    [
         set target item 0 itinerary
         set itinerary remove-item 0 itinerary
    ]
]
```

or is there a best practice for this type of thing that I haven't found?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to check for an empty agentset, replace `empty? target` with `not any? target`. You use `empty?` to check for empty lists, while `any?` or `not any?` are for agentsets.

Comment: interesting, I'm working with agentsets using `if target = nobody` and if itinerary = []` currently and it seems to work fine. I realized using lists made no sense per this [forum post][1]


  [1]: http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/How-to-convert-agentsets-to-a-list-td4864408.html

Comment: To represent the absence of a single agent, use `nobody`.